# Why use fully-qualified names?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, namespaces

Since the introduction of the [var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) keyword, why would you want to use why use fully-qualified names?

`var` effectively reduces the typing for variable declarations. Hence, it becomes possible to keep the full declaration without bloating the code. This makes me wonder, why would you even want to declare `namespace` usage?

```
// A lot of typing, but unambiguous.
System.Drawing.Point a = new System.Drawing.Point();

// using System.Drawing, Point possibly ambiguous.
Point b = new Point();

// using System.Drawing, Point possibly ambiguous.
var c = new Point();

// Less typing, still unambiguous.
var d = new System.Drawing.Point();
```

What is the best practice here?

Comment: What's the point? If there's an ambiguity, the code will fail to compile anyway... Just use `using` clauses, and use the fully qualified name in the (usually rare) ambiguous cases...

Comment: Why not to go even farther - why using all this long names like "Point" and "Stream" when 2-3 characters are enough like "pPx" and "s$e" (and you'll save whole bunch of money on obfuscators too).

Comment: @Thomas, The code might fail to compile, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @l33t, well, can you give me an example where an ambiguity compiles successfully? It's one of the most important principles in the C# language: the compiler never tries to guess; if there's a doubt, it fails and lets you resolve the ambiguity. If it succeeds, then you can be sure there isn't another symbol with the same name in the current scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be less about namespaces and more about the use of static typing inside code.  The main argument I have heard for not using `var` extends to when the variable type isn't readily apparent by glancing at the declaration.  Consider the following code:

```
var readyTasks = _config.GetTasks().Where(x => x.Ready);
```

How on earth are you going to know what `readyTasks` is?  `IEnumerable` is a given, considering what `Where()` returns, but beyond that the only way to get the type out of this is to mouse over `var` and let Visual Studio ferret it out for you.  This gets even more complicated as LINQ statements get longer, enumerables get thrust into logical structures like `foreach` loops, the list goes on and on and on.

Proponents of `var` (of which I am one), will counter that this is a tiny thing to reap the numerously fewer hassles that `var` will produce for you in the long run.   Static type declarations have never been a consideration of programmer comfort, ever.  They are for compilers first and foremost.  Therefore, it does not seem to make sense to hold onto this artifact simply because you're used to it.

Comment: I disagree with this strongly.  The code above needs a type reference.  Sometimes you have to view code in text quickly without a working copy of Visual Studio on that PC.  "Hovering with var" is not always available.

Answer (score 13):

Namespaces are only really useful for a few reasons:

1. Helping to distinguish between classes with the same name
2. To help 'structure' the project into meaningful pieces

As Oded mentioned, these reasons alone can be very important - although uncommon, ambiguity is not impossible and in this case using namespaces would be a necessity.

Find out more about namespaces [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Which are, actually, really good "things" to have.

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is actually *Why use fully-qualified names?* and not *Why use namespaces?*.

Namespaces are very important within any `Object Oriented` language. If you have 2 classes with the same name (which happens quite often within the .NET framework already), how are you supposed to distinguish between them? That's the point of a namespace - and if there are 2 classes with the same name within the same namespace, the code won't compile. (Unless, of course, they're partial classes, which is an entirely different story).

On instance of this that I run into often is a `List`. We use `NHibernate` on a few projects here, which has it's own `List`. If I'm instantiating a `List`, I can't just do:

```
var list = new List<string>();
```

.. because the compiler won't know if I want a `NHibernate.Mapping.List` or a `System.Collections.Generic.List`.

The `var` keyword is very useful for `type inference`, but that's not helpful if you don't have the proper `using` statements or `Fully Qualified` names on the other end.

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are used
1. To define scope
2. To distinguish same class name in different namespaces/projects/assemblies.

Usage of var is not linked to namespaces in anyway. Less typing is taken care by namespace aliases.

[Using Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For throwaway test apps (e.g. checking Stack Overflow answers), I don't use a namespace. For anything else, I do. It's just an organization thing - if you're going to reuse code, it's helpful to separate it from other code you're also reusing in the same context. What I mean is, if you're creating an app using LibraryX and LibraryY, it's useful to be able to differentiate between them within the app. It's possible that they both use the same class names, for example - which will make the code ugly if you don't use namespaces.

Aside from anything else, if you're coding with Visual Studio it's actually more work not to include a namespace - you've got to modify the project to give it an empty default namespace.

For Information regarding Naming refer to: [Namespace Naming Convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)